# How can i include one code inside one other shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, href, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I am trying to add the acf field href on the shortcode.

This is the 1 code

```
<?php global $post;
        if( get_field('url',$taxonomy . '_' . $termId) ): ?>
<?php
    $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
    $termId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
 the_field('url', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
  ?>id2=<?php echo $current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The shortcode.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mycred_link href="the_1_code_inside_here"]View portfolio[/mycred_link]'); ?>
```

Comment: Since you did not display your full code it's quite tough to understand actually what you want. However, you can see this code https://pastebin.com/ZCE2S43r  and get an idea regarding your question

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i place an better explanation.